# Enable Comments for Portfolio post type on Woodmart theme

Tags: comments, custom-post-type, portfolio

I use Woodmart theme and on the Woodmart theme has intentionally disabled comments for the Portfolio post type and the option is not available in the theme settings.
So, How can I add Comment on it?

Also I use this code and doesn't work

```
function woodmart_enable_comments_on_portfolio() {
 add_post_type_support( 'portfolio', 'comments' );
}add_action( 'init', 'woodmart_enable_comments_on_portfolio' );
```

The other code is:

```
function woodmart_enable_comments_on_portfolio( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'portfolio' ) {
        $args['supports'][] = 'comments';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'woodmart_enable_comments_on_portfolio', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find the solution
Use this code and replace it on single-portfolio.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying single project
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php 
    
    // Get content width and sidebar position
    $content_class = woodmart_get_content_class();

?>


<div class="site-content <?php echo esc_attr( $content_class ); ?>" role="main">

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="portfolio-single-content">
                    <?php the_content( esc_html__( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'woodmart' ) ); ?>
                </div>

                <!-- Enable Comment On Portfolio Page -->
                <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    if ( woodmart_get_opt('page_comments') && (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;
                 ?>
                <br>
                <!-- Enable Comment On Portfolio Page -->
                <?php if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'portfolio_navigation' ) ) woodmart_posts_navigation(); ?>

                <?php
                $args = woodmart_get_related_projects_args( get_the_ID() );

                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( woodmart_get_opt( 'portfolio_related' ) ) {
                    $style = woodmart_get_opt( 'portoflio_style' );

                    if ( 'parallax' === $style ) {
                        woodmart_enqueue_js_library( 'panr-parallax-bundle' );
                        woodmart_enqueue_js_script( 'portfolio-effect' );
                    }

                    woodmart_enqueue_portfolio_loop_styles( $style );

                    woodmart_enqueue_js_library( 'photoswipe-bundle' );
                    woodmart_enqueue_inline_style( 'photoswipe' );
                    woodmart_enqueue_js_script( 'portfolio-photoswipe' );
                    echo woodmart_generate_posts_slider(
                        array(
                            'title'                   => esc_html__( 'Related projects', 'woodmart' ),
                            'slides_per_view'         => 3,
                            'hide_pagination_control' => 'yes',
                            'custom_sizes'            => apply_filters( 'woodmart_portfolio_related_custom_sizes', false ),
                        ),
                        $query
                    );
                }
                ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- .site-content -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```